# Laravel First Or New

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I seem to be getting the same error when I use UpdateOrNew or FirstOrNew in Laravel, to the best of my knowledge I have implemented the code correctly.

**Current Code**

```
    $updateOrCreate = Rating::firstOrNew(
        array(
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'video_id' => $_POST['videoId']
            )
    );

    $updateOrCreate->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $updateOrCreate->video_id = $_POST['videoId'];
    $updateOrCreate->rating =   $_POST['rating'];

    if($updateOrCreate->save()){
        echo "saved";
    }else{
        echo "failed";
        print_r($_POST);
    };
```

**Error**

```
error: {type:Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException, message:user_id,…}
file: "/home/celeb/public_html/dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php"
line: 411
message: "user_id"
type: "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException"
```

Comment: did u check with response on chrome ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to enable mass assignment in your model as such:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email');

}
```

So any field that can be mass assigned should be in the $fillable variable.

Assigning values without mass assignment:

```
$user = new User;
$user->id = 3;
$user->name = "Joe";

$user->save();
```

Assigning values *with* mass assignment:

```
$userDetails = array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Joe');
$user = User::create($userDetails);
```

Comment: My struggle here is understanding how assigning it to one entry is mass assignment?

Comment: Mass assignment is using an array of field values to create a record, rather than doing it one field at a time.

Comment: I dont understand this? Sorry but doesn't eloquent map the database?

Comment: @Brent To prevent any table field to be assigned, by accident or by ill intent, Eloquent only allows assignment on those fields that you have defined in the class property `$fillable`.

Comment: What I don't understand is why the `firstOrNew` method should trigger a mass assignment exception since it is merely *looking* at the database, not attempting to save anything. For example why on earth should this code throw a MAE: `$tour = Tour::firstOrNew(array('id' => $this->request['id']));` All it is saying is basically "look and see if there is a row in the database with that ID, if so then return the row, if not, then create a new object with the relevant properties". It isn't saving any data so what is the damn problem...

Answer (score 2):

"You may also use the create method to save a new model in a single line. The inserted model instance will be returned to you from the method. However, before doing so, you will need to specify either a fillable or guarded attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment". [See Laravel Documentation on Eloquent Insert, Update, Delete ]
(http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#insert-update-delete)

That means, only the create method can protect your codes from mass assignment:

`/*$user=*/  User::create(array(
            'name'     => 'Max',
            'email'    => 'example@example.com'
        ));`

When using the create method, you specify the model's name which is User from the example above. This model (usually User.php) is the place where you assign the mass assignable variables:

`protected $fillable = ['name', 'email'];`